# How to do logging when writing an Visual Studio MEF extension

Tags: visual-studio, logging, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension using MEF an I'm wondering how to add logging to the code.
When writing a VsPackage one could use the "Action Log" like shown in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166359%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But this isn't possible in a MEF extension.

How should I do my logging? Is it even possible to write to the VS access log using a MEF extension? Should I do my own logging using nlog or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the `IVsActivityLog`. The only thing that changes is the way you get access to the `IVsActivityLog` instance. Instead of this:

```
IVsActivityLog log = GetService(typeof(SVsActivityLog)) as IVsActivityLog;
```

You would first `[Import]` the [`SVsServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.svsserviceprovider.aspx):

```
[Import] internal SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider = null;
```

Then you can call `IServiceProvider.GetService`:

```
IVsActivityLog log = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsActivityLog)) as IVsActivityLog;
```

Comment: Did this, ran my extension, watched it call LogEntry(), but can't find an ActivityLog.xml file anywhere in AppData (except for one that hasn't been updated for 10 days). Any ideas?